# Splitting string into two separate

Tags: java

Well what I meant with that, I create variable with type String and then when I load file, I have to save content in one variable in which case that variable is "TextFromFile", after loading it, I wanted to split it into two separate one and save it in array, after that I just wanted to display two separate strings on screen. That`s the idea.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package zadania1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Zadania1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String TextFromFile = "";
        Zadania1 zad = new Zadania1(); 
        TextFromFile = zad.NacitajObsahZoSubora("C:\\Users\\Ivan\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        String[] pole = TextFromFile.split("[ \\ ]");
        System.out.println("Frist matrica " + pole[0] +" Second matrica: " + pole[1] +"");
    }

    public String NacitajObsahZoSubora(String fileName)
    {
        String text = "", tmp;
        try 
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(file);
            try (BufferedReader fromFile = new BufferedReader(input)) 
            {
                while((tmp = fromFile.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    text = text + "\n" + tmp;
                }
                System.out.println("Obsah suboru:\n" + text);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {            
        }
        return text;
    }

    public void ZapisObsahDoSubora(String fileName, String writeText)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(file);
            try (PrintWriter toFile = new PrintWriter(output)) 
            {
                toFile.println("" + writeText);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {   
        }
    }
}
```

Only this part is showing me that array is out of bounce:

```
String[] pole = TextFromFile.split("[ \\ ]");
        System.out.println("Frist matrica " + pole[0] +" Second matrica: " + pole[1] +"");
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>         at zadania1.Zadania1.main(Zadania1.java:24)

Comment: It means there's a line in your file that doesn't include a slash or a space (probably an empty line?) and therefore `line.split("[ \\ ]")` returns an array with length of 1. Please attach your txt file for a more educated guess

Comment: Ahh sorry here is why my txt file contain: [1,2,3;4,5,6;][9,8;7,-6;50,61;]

Comment: Just like that?! One line with all these characters?

Comment: Yes that it.....

Comment: So what's your expected output of `TextFromFile.split("[ \\ ]")`?

Comment: Well what I meant with that, I create variable with type String and then when I load file, I have to save content in one variable in which case that variable is "TextFromFile", after loading it, I wanted to split it into two separate one and save it in array, after that I just wanted to display two separate strings on screen. That`s the idea.

Comment: Use [edit] option to provide more info/clarifications about your question. Don't hide it in comments section (not everyone willing to help you will be also willing to search for every bit of important information post elsewhere beside main question).

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood from the comments, assuming your input is in the form of:

```
[1,2,3;4,5,6;][9,8;7,-6;50,61;]
```

You need to use another regex in your split, which involves a look-behind:

```
String input = "[1,2,3;4,5,6;][9,8;7,-6;50,61;]";
String[] pole = input.split("(?<=\\])");
System.out.println("Frist matrica " + pole[0] +" Second matrica: " + pole[1] +"");

// Output:
// Frist matrica [1,2,3;4,5,6;] Second matrica: [9,8;7,-6;50,61;]
```

Comment: So close the question, for next generations' sake :)